# why does this error being shown mostly when i try to return string?

Tags: c, stack, memory-address

You are given a string s consisting of lowercase English letters. A duplicate removal consists of choosing two adjacent and equal letters and removing them.

We repeatedly make duplicate removals on s until we no longer can.

Return the final string after all such duplicate removals have been made. It can be proven that the answer is unique.

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack{
    char *items;
    int top;
};
#define max 100000
typedef struct stack st;
void push(st *stk,char c){
    if(stk->top==max-1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        stk->items[++stk->top]=c;
    }
}
void pop(st *stk){
    if(stk->top==-1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        stk->top--;
    }
}
char * removeDuplicates(char * s){
    st *str;
    int l=strlen(s);
    str=malloc(sizeof(st));
    str->items=malloc(l*sizeof(char));
    int i;
    str->top=-1;
    for(i=0;i<l;++i){
        int flag=0;
        int j=i+1;
        while(s[j]==s[i]){
            j++;
            flag=1;
        }
        if(s[i]==str->items[str->top]){
            pop(str);
        }
        else if(flag==0){
            push(str,s[i]);
        }
        else{
            i=j-1;
        }
    }
    str->items[str->top + 1]='\0';
    return str->items;
}
```

=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000004f at pc 0x560f21617b67 bp 0x7fff66262090 sp 0x7fff66262080
READ of size 1 at 0x60200000004f thread T0
#2 0x7f93db0310b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x60200000004f is located 1 bytes to the left of 6-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000056)
allocated by thread T0 here:
#0 0x7f93dbc76bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
#3 0x7f93db0310b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 07 fa fa fa 00 00 fa[fa]06 fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
Addressable:           00
Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
Heap left redzone:       fa
Freed heap region:       fd
Stack left redzone:      f1
Stack mid redzone:       f2
Stack right redzone:     f3
Stack after return:      f5
Stack use after scope:   f8
Global redzone:          f9
Global init order:       f6
Poisoned by user:        f7
Container overflow:      fc
Array cookie:            ac
Intra object redzone:    bb
ASan internal:           fe
Left alloca redzone:     ca
Right alloca redzone:    cb
Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING

Answer (score 0):

One error I see:

```
char * removeDuplicates(char * s){
    st *str;
    int l=strlen(s);
    str=malloc(sizeof(st));
```

That last line should be `malloc sizeof(*st)`.